# Button into bulleted list

Tags: css

I am creating a pricing table, I would like to add a `button` into a `<li></li>` with a small word,  the problem is that my elements are not placed correctly.

If I use a `<br />` the problem is solved, but I looking for a better solution please.

```
<li>1000 Email Boxes <br/>
    <button>Add to Cart</button>
</li>
```

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 70%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap : wrap; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 10;
  width: 0;
}

.flex-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.package {
  border: 1px solid ;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.package .header {
  background-color: #F4B7DB;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.package .highlight {
  background-color: #29b6f6;
}

.package li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}


button {
  background-color: #29b6f6;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .15em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .75em 1.5em;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <ul class="package">
      <li class="header">Basic</li>
      <li>20GB Storage</li>
      <li>100 Domains</li>
      <li>1TB Bandwidth</li>
      <li>1000 Email Boxes <br/>
        <button>Add to Cart</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your text with `block` DOM such as `div`

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 70%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap : wrap; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 10;
  width: 0;
}

.flex-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.package {
  border: 1px solid ;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.package .header {
  background-color: #F4B7DB;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.package .highlight {
  background-color: #29b6f6;
}

.package li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}


button {
  background-color: #29b6f6;
  border: none;
  border-radius: .15em;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: .75em 1.5em;
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <ul class="package">
      <li class="header">Basic</li>
      <li>20GB Storage</li>
      <li>100 Domains</li>
      <li>1TB Bandwidth</li>
      <li><div>1000 Email Boxes</div>
        <button>Add to Cart</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>
```